# PHP code is showing in the webpage while executing

Tags: php, session

i am new to php I am trying to write a registration page.But something goes wrong.Every time i try to execute the code i get something like this in my page

Database details

Db name: cibil,
table name: table {id,username,password,email
      }

```
 query($sql)===true) { $_SESSION['message']='You are successfully added';
       $_SESSION['username']=$user; $_SESSION['email']=$email; 
       header(location:page.php); } else{ $_SESSION['message']='Something went wrong'; } } ?>
```

My code is

```
<? php
session_start()
$_SESSION['message']='';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
    {  
        $conn=new mysqli('localhost','root','','cibil') or die("error");
        $user=$_POST['user'];
        $pass=$_POST['pass'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $sql="INSERT INFO table (username, password,email)VALUES('$user','$pass','$email')";
        if($conn->query($sql)===true)
        { 
            $_SESSION['message']='You are successfully added';
            $_SESSION['username']=$user;
            $_SESSION['email']=$email;
            header(location:page.php);
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['message']='Something went wrong';
        }

    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Register form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reg_style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="h1">
<h1>Registration Page</h1>
</div>
<div id="err"><? php echo $_SESSION['message'] ?></div>
<div id='form'>
<form method="post" name='form' onsubmit="return rvalidate()" action="">
  <p class="error">*Required</p>
  <label for="user">Enter Your Name* : </label>
  <input id="user" type="text" name="user" class="field">
  <span class='error'></span><br><br>
  <label for="email">Enter Your Email : </label>
  <input id="email" type="text" name="email" class="field">
  <br><br>
  <label for="pass">Enter Your Password* : </label>
  <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" class="field"><span class='error'></span><br><br>
  <label for="rpass">Re-Enter Your Password* : </label>
  <input type="password" id="rpass" name="rpass" class="field"><span class='error'></span><br><br>
<input type="submit" id='submit' class="field" value="SUBMIT" onclick="validate();" >
</form>
</div>
<br><br>
<div id="login_text">
<b>If you are already register </b><br><a href="login.php">Click here</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var error=document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    var user=document.form.user;
    var pass=document.form.pass;
    var rpass=document.form.rpass;
function validate()
{
    if(user.value==="")
    {
        error[0].innerHTML="*Enter Your name";
        user.setAttribute("style","border-color:green");
    }else{
        error[0].innerHTML="";
        user.setAttribute("style","border-color:initial");
    }
    if(pass.value=="")
    {
        error[1].innerHTML="*Password is Required";
        pass.setAttribute("style","border-color:green");
    }else{
        error[1].innerHTML="";
        pass.setAttribute("style","border-color:initial");
    }
    if(pass.value!==rpass.value)
    {
        error[2].innerHTML="*Password Missmatch";
        rpass.setAttribute("style","border-color:green");
    }else{
        error[2].innerHTML="";
        rpass.setAttribute("style","border-color:initial");
    }

}
function rvalidate()
{
    if (error[0].innerHTML=="" && error[1].innerHTML=="" && error[2].innerHTML=="") {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help.........

Comment: Where is Problem ??

Comment: I think the text dispayed that you removed with your edit was helpful to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not executed and shown as text because you have a space between ? and php at the start of the code.  Try to start with `<?php
session_start();`. Then you will be able to debug all the rest :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="err"><? php echo $_SESSION['message']
```

If you notice there is a space between the ? And PHP, that may affect what is bring output. There is a few areas where your quotes don't match so if you check if the quotes aren't closing each other in places they shouldn't be closed then you should be okay

Is your filename correct? If it is a .htm or .html file it may not parse the PHP which could also be another issue you're having

Answer (score 0):

You have a space at the opening of your php code :

```
<? php
```

should be :

```
<?php
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code:

```
$sql="INSERT INFO table (username, password,email)VALUES('$user','$pass','$email')";
```

Must be without `...`:

```
$sql="INSERT INFO table (username, password,email)VALUES($user, $pass, $email)";
```

Comment: no there must be  quotes around the values, unless the values are numeric.